# how to get word and decimal value separate in array using regex

Tags: c#, regex

need following output :

1. decimal value must be as it is
2. if we use "()" in input string as given in variable `input1 = "pops + nts(1.75%)"` , then its should remove that closing and opening bracket

expected output: `[0]="pops" [1]="nts" [2]="1.75"`

[image: current output as given in image , need output for 3rd and 4rth array element value must be in one array element like 1.75]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //string input1 = "pops + nts(1.75%)";
    string input2 = "pops + nts1.75%";
    string[] Resul2 = Regex.Split(input2, @"(\W+)(\D+)(\d+)");
 }
```

Comment: Lots of info missing here. What are `pops` and `nts`? Are they constants? Will the format only vary by parentheses?

Comment: Can `pops` and `nts` contain digits? Or end with digits? There can be no solution if there is a var called `nts1` followed with a `1.75%` glued to it.

Comment: Try `(\w+)\s*\+\s*([^\W\d]+)\(?(\d*\.\d+)`. See http://ideone.com/ttAMyY

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew , thanks it worked , i am curious to know how exactly it works , can you explain it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `nts` or `pops` cannot have digits at the end, else, your task is impossible to complete.

I suggest

```
(\w+)\s*\+\s*(\w+?)\(?(\d*\.\d+)
```

to be used with `Regex.Match`. See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cw%2b)%5cs*%5c%2b%5cs*(%5cw%2b%3f)%5c(%3f(%5cd*%5c.%5cd%2b)&i=pops+%2b+nt1s11.75%25+-+pops+%2b+nt1s(11.75%25))

**Details**:

- `(\w+)` - 1 or more word chars (Group 1)
- `\s*\+\s*` - a `+` with 0+ whitespaces around it
- `(\w+?)` - 1 or more word chars (Group 2), but as few as possible
- `\(?` an optional `(` (one or zero)
- `(\d*\.\d+)` - Group 3 matching float/integer values (allowing `.XX` kind of floats)

See [C# demo](http://ideone.com/rSdK4j):

```
var s = "pops + nt1s11.75%";
var pat = @"(\w+)\s*\+\s*(\w+?)\(?(\d*\.\d+)";
var r = Regex.Match(s, pat);
if (r.Success)
    Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\n{2}", r.Groups[1].Value, r.Groups[2].Value, r.Groups[3].Value);
```

Output:

```
pops
nt1s
11.75
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented - not a lot to go on, But

```
(\w+)\s*\+\s*([\w-[\d]]+)\(?(\d*\.\d*)
```

will get you what you ask for.

[See it here at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5Cw%2B)%5Cs*%5C%2B%5Cs*(%5Cw%2B)%5C(%3F(%5Cd*%5C.%5Cd*)&i=pops%20%2B%20nts(12.75%25)).

It captures a word, matches optional space, followed by a `+`, followed by optional space. Then it captures a word **not** containing digits, optionally matches a `(`, and finally captures a decimal number. The rest is ignored. To be more strict with the input add start and end anchors:

```
^(\w+)\s*\+\s*([\w-[\d]]+)\(?(\d*\.\d*)%\)$
```

Comment: first code worked after removing first d " * ".                                            string[] Resul2 = Regex.Split(input2, @"(\w+)\s*\+\s*(\w+)\(?(\d+\.\d*)");

Comment: @yashfale: No, it won't work with `pops + nts11.75%`, see [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=\(%5cw%2b\)%5cs*%5c%2b%5cs*\(%5cw%2b\)%5c\(%3f\(%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd*\)&i=pops+%2b+nts11.75%25). Please answer my comment to the question to clarify.

Comment: @ClasG , yes you are right if i use nts12.75% then it gives me .75 only with "/d+"  , even i use "/d*" it gives .75 still both are not working (note :  if digits are not in bracket then it does not works like pops + nts11.75)% )

Comment: Sorry for that - sloppy of me. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this is you can try to use delimiter character so that        you can get the best result of a string you wanted to be.. This is just an option.
You can do something like this:

```
<pre>
        string input2 = "pops; +; nts;1.75%";
        char c = ';';
        string[] i2 = input2.Split(c);
</pre> 
Hope it helps.
```